# `splint` and dynamically allocated arrays: Returned storage not completely defined

Tags: c, memory, splint

I am working on a little project and want to make it `splint`-proof for kicks. I am allocating an array and passing it on to a function that generates values and assigns them to array elements, i.e.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void generate(int* arr, int len);

int main() {
    int length = 10;
    int* array = malloc((size_t) (length * sizeof(int)));

    if (array == NULL)
        return 1;

    generate(array, length);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);

    free(array);
    return 0;
}

void generate(int* arr, int len) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        arr[i] = i;
}
```

`splint` complains about this:

```
test.c: (in function main)
test.c:14:18: Passed storage array not completely defined (*array is undefined): generate (array, ...)
  Storage derivable from a parameter, return value or global is not defined.
  Use /*@out@*/ to denote passed or returned storage which need not be defined.
  (Use -compdef to inhibit warning)
   test.c:8:58: Storage *array allocated
```

Fair enough. Returning a default value to avoid having uninitialized storage around is not a bad idea, and I modify the program as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*@null@*/
static int* generate(int len);

int main(void) {
    int length = 10;
    int* array = generate(length);

    if (array == NULL)
        return 1;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);

    free(array);
    return 0;
}

int* generate(int len) {
    int i;
    int* arr = malloc((size_t) (len * sizeof(int)));

    if (arr != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            arr[i] = i;
        return arr;
    } else
        return NULL;
}
```

I would have thought this gives a good definition to the `arr` array, and yet running `splint` again:

```
testnew.c: (in function empty)
testnew.c:33:16: Returned storage arr not completely defined (*arr is undefined): arr
  Storage derivable from a parameter, return value or global is not defined.
  Use /*@out@*/ to denote passed or returned storage which need not be defined.
  (Use -compdef to inhibit warning)
   testnew.c:28:53: Storage *arr allocated
```

What exactly does "completely defined" mean here then? I don't want to add an `/*@out@*/` annotation because I don't understand how the code can be interpreted as anything other than "return an array of 'len' integers or NULL". Is it good practice to use initializer functions instead of calling `malloc` directly?

Edit: *Why not just use `calloc`?*

When using `calloc` instead of `malloc` in either case `splint` produces no warnings anymore, but I'm not sure why that should matter if I'm not reading from the array before initializing. The default values are not necessarily zero, and I want to be able to `realloc` the arrays. I'm not chasing minuscule performance improvements, but at this point I am simply curious if you can 'completely define' uninitialized memory at runtime.

Comment: "Use /*@out@*/ to denote passed **or returned storage** which need not be defined." To **define** storage (or a function), the code contains all the information the compiler needs to set aside that storage (data segment or stack or...). Allocating a variable amount of heap storage is not **defined** at compile time.

Comment: `int a;` **defines** an uninitialised memory location (typically 4 bytes). **Define** is important to the compiler. **Define** has no meaning to the runtime initialisation of data.

Comment: So does this mean 'definition' has nothing to do with memory?

Comment: No, definition is all about memory _at compile time_... Code can **declare** the type of a token (eg: `extern int foo;`, `void func( int a);` or `struct ss { char arr[10] };`, and, as long as all declarations are the same, they can be repeated 'n' times. The compiler sets aside storage (or generates code) when a variable is **defined** (instantiated) (or a function is defined with its body). **Define** is all about memory at compile time. What the code does at run-time (malloc) is up to the code; none of the compiler's business...

Comment: Correction: What the binary **executable** does at run-time (malloc) is up to the **executable**; none of the compiler's business.

Comment: Hopefully my final comment... I don't know "splint", but guess that it is analysing source code, looking for flaws. There are untold ways to allocate memory during execution, and "splint" is covering its bases when it put the onus on the programmer to 'mark' the code in places where "...storage which need not be defined." (Imagine 'malloc()' appears in another compilation unit (source file).) Seems if you want to pass 'splint', you need to "mark up" your code as the splint message advises.

Comment: That does explain the warning but not how I can avoid it. I do mark up the code with `splint` directive comments when I understand how it works (see `/*@null@*/`), but I need those arrays to be allocated at runtime and I cannot get `splint` to shut up with just `/*@out@*/` without passing `-compdef` of `-mustdefine`. Thanks for the help, but it seems we will have to wait for someone with more knowledge of `splint` to stop by for more info...

Comment: I used splint several years ago and finally gave up to use it for memory checks. I watched its development many years using it regularly, but did not since my last usage, now assuming that it did not evolve. However, I remember some examples in its documentation. Did you try to understand and apply that? Perhaps I'll find some spare time to look into your issue. IIRC there is a mailing list or other means of community chatter. Did you ask there?